# Automated/Scripted Video Editing

Tags: editing, automation

I am looking for a scripting language that can handle cutting together 50+ mp4 files.  In addition to this I'd also like it if I can provide a text file with the date of each video and make some sort of slightly opaque box containing the date that I can burn over the video.  Is there a good tool out there for this?  Most of the stuff I've found only works on avi files.

Comment: Welcome derek :) you can use ffmpeg and call it as subprocess via python. For the ffmpeg part, you will find all necessary informations on this site. I would write an answer, but your question is a bit too broad. Maybe let us know what files you have and what exactly you want to do with it. Anyway, enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following technologies:

1. ffmpeg + command line
2. Adobe After Effects + ExtendScript language (based on JavaScript)
3. Sony Vegas Pro + C# language (or any other Microsoft .NET language)